# Issues with mocking functions used by mapping function in Spark apply

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function `applier` that uses Sparks `GroupedData.applyInPandas`. The `applyInPandas` maps the grouped data with a function named `mapper`, which in turn calls a function `get_value`. When unit testing, I need to mock the `get_value`-function. The reason for this is that in my original code, the `get_value`-function has a side-effect I need to avoid while testing.

The issue is that the `get_value`-function does get mocked, but the `applyInPandas`-call does not pick it up. I've constructed this minimal example to illustrate the issue:

```
# funs.py
def get_value():
  return 'not mocked'

def mapper(df):
  t = get_value()
  return df.assign(v=t)

def applier(df):
    print(mapper(df.toPandas()))
    return df.groupby('id').applyInPandas(mapper, schema='id long, v string')
```

and

```
# tests.py
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock
from funs import applier

def get_value_mock():
    return 'mocked'

df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd')],
  ('id', 'v')
)

class Testfuns(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('funs.get_value', get_value_mock)
    def test_applier(self):
        applier(df).show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=['first-arg-is-ignored'], exit=False)
```

Running this outputs:

```
   id       v
0   1  mocked
1   1  mocked
2   2  mocked
3   2  mocked
.+---+----------+
| id|         v|
+---+----------+
|  1|not mocked|
|  1|not mocked|
|  2|not mocked|
|  2|not mocked|
+---+----------+
```

Which tells me that the `get_value`-function was mocked in the `print`-call made by `applier`, but not in the `applyInPandas`-call.

I would expect the `get_value`-function to be mocked either everywhere or nowhere in `funs.py`.

Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on here?